# Logic App copy file from FTP to Blob but ignore already copied files

Tags: azure-logic-apps

Im setting up a logic app that should Trigger when a file is added or modified in a specific path on a FTP server and will then copy this file to a storage account. However, I have tried multiple setups within the logic app but can not seem to get it right. I want the setup to only copy the files that does not already exist in the storage account.

I have the following setup right now :
When a file is added or modified (FTP) -> List files in folder (FTP) -> For each File in folder (FTP) -> Create blob

This setup will trigger correctly and will copy each file to the specified storage account.

I have also tried with different condition but it doesnt seem to work. For example I tried adding another step which was (FTP) -> List files in folder (FTP) -> List blobs -> Condition List blobs is not equal to List Files -> If TRUE -> For each File in folder (FTP) -> Create blob

Does anyone have any idea on how I can get this working?

Greetings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is hare to explain it and I think share the template is also not easy for you to deploy it. So I post the screenshots of my logic app below for your reference.

The screenshot below is the overall architecture of my logic app:

[image]

Below is the architecture of "For each":

[image]

The screenshot below is the architecture of "For each 2":

[image]

The screenshot below is the architecture of "Condition 2":

[image]

By the way, please click "..." beside your "For each" and change the settings as below screenshot shows(This change is very important because cycles in a "Foreach" loop run in parallel. If you don't do this change, the value of your variable in logic app will be incorrect. I wasted too much time here.)

[image]

Comment: Wow, much appreciation Hury Shen! Works like a charm and ignore already copied files. Will use this method to other logic apps aswell. Only thing I struggle with regarding Logic Apps is that sometimes when I edit a Logic App workflow too many times it stops working? Is it just for me or for everyone? When that happens I need to create a freshly new Logic App and enter the same workflow and boom, it works instantly. Really weird.

Thanks for sharing your setup :)

Comment: @Mattias Thanks for your reply, but I'm sorry that I haven't met the same problem as yours'.